Finding the average sale price for all genres associated with an author
I have the following index of books in Elasticsearch:
{
  "id": 345356,
  "price": 35.99,
  "author": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "John Doe"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Jane Doe"
    }
  ],
  "genre": [
    {
      "id": 23,
      "name": "Sports"
    },
    {
      "id": 34,
      "name": "Adventure"
    }
  ]
}

I am trying to find the average book price for all of the genres that a given author has published in.
I tried the below query but it's only giving the prices within the documents that contain the given author. I'm looking for the prices for those genres for all of the documents. So, for instance, if we're talking about "John Doe", the query would return the sum of book prices for all documents that contain the genres "Sports" or "Adventure".
And this doesn't need to be a terms aggregation either.
GET books/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "inner": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "author"
      },
      "aggregations": {
        "aggs_filters": {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "author.id": 1
            }
          },
          "aggregations": {
            "reverseNested": {
              "reverse_nested": {
                "path": "genre"
              },
              "aggregations": {
                "genres": {
                  "terms": {
                    "field": "genre.id",
                    "size": 1000
                  },
                  "aggregations": {
                    "back_to_root": {
                      "reverse_nested": {},
                      "aggregations": {
                        "sum_of_prices": {
                          "sum": {
                            "field": "price"
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}```


You couldn't solve this issue with such mapping. See my answers to a similar question
